# List is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two classes Book and Basket. In this scenario, basket has more than one books. I have to serialize them in a proper order. I wrote a serialize query but it doesnt work. When im trying runserver, it returns

> homepage.views.Book object at 0x7f1afe3a8ef0 is not JSON serializable

## CLASSES

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self,bookId,bookName,bookPrice,bookAuthor,bookYear,bookStar,bookCatagory):
        self.bookId=bookId
        self.bookName=bookName
        self.bookPrice=bookPrice
        self.bookAuthor=bookAuthor
        self.bookYear=bookYear
        self.bookStar=bookStar
        self.bookCatagory=bookCatagory



class Basket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numberOfProduct = None
        self.validate = None
        self.paymentValidate = None
        self.books = list()


class UserClass(object):
    def __init__(self,id,name,surname,address):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.address = address
        self.basket = Basket()

def dummy(user):
      book = Book("1","1984","20TL","George Orwell","1999","4","Drama")
book1 = Book("2", "Verwandlung", "25TL", "Franz Kafka", "2001", "5", "Drama")
book2 = Book("3", "Game of Thrones", "50TL", "George Martin", "2007", "5", "Drama")
    user.basket.books.append(book)
    user.basket.books.append(book1)
    user.basket.books.append(book2)


@api_view(['GET'])
def test(request):
    query = User.objects.filter(userName="name").first()
    if (query != None):
        userId = query.userId
        name = query.name
        surname = query.surname
        address = query.address
        newUser = UserClass(userId, name, surname, address)
        dummy(newUser)

        serializer_class = BasketSerializer(
            data={'userId': newUser.id, 'name': newUser.name, 'surname': newUser.surname, 'address': newUser.address,'book': newUser.basket.books})
        serializer_class.is_valid()

    return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

## SERIALIZER

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    bookId = serializers.IntegerField()


class BasketSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    userId = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=21)
    surname = serializers.CharField(max_length=21)
    address = serializers.CharField(max_length=51)
    book = BookSerializer(many=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: In your view `Book` class object is used ( not model) and you are assigning it  to model in the line ( user.basket.books ?)

Answer (score 0):

This code is for deserialization.

For serialization that you are trying to perform, replace

```
serializer_class = BasketSerializer(
        data={'userId': newUser.id, 'name': newUser.name, 'surname': newUser.surname, 'address': newUser.address,'book': newUser.basket.books})
serializer_class.is_valid()
```

by:

```
serializer_class = BasketSerializer(
        instance={'userId': newUser.id, 'name': newUser.name, 'surname': newUser.surname, 'address': newUser.address,'book': newUser.basket.books})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your classes need to inherit from Django's model.Models.

`from django.db import models`

For example:

`class Book(models.Model):
        bookId= models.IntegerField()
        bookName= models.CharcField()
        ...`

That way, the Django Rest Framework will serialize. :)